# re:test() XPath to HtmlAgilityPack (get all p tags with matched regex internal)

Tags: c#, html, xpath, html-agility-pack

I want all `<p>=.+=</p>` tags.  The Regex works on its own, without the `<p>` tags.

Here's my XPath: `"//p[re:test(.,'^=.+=$', 'i')]"`

But I'm getting an exception when I plug it into,

```
HtmlNodeCollection pNodes = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//p[re:test(.,'^=.+=$', 'i')]");
```

The exception is:

> Namespace Manager or XsltContext
>   needed. This query has a prefix,
>   variable, or user-defined function.

Edit: The Html is generated by FCKEditor and has no namespace defined.  Do I need to set something for this to work?

The HTML:

```
<p><style type="text/css">
h2 a { color: black; }</style></p>
<p>----</p>
<h2>test <a href="http://searisen.com">link</a></h2>
<p>== Heading 2 ==</p>
<p>----</p>
<p>=== Heading [http://searisen.com SeaRisen.com] ===</p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you have is due to the fact that the expression `re:test` uses an XPATH function named `test` (declared in a namespace whose prefix is `re`), that is unknown to the XSLT context.

I don't know where you got that expression from, but it's not standard, so it means nothing in the Html Agility Pack context :-)

For indepth explanation, see this cool article here: [Adding Custom Functions to XPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms950806.aspx). Note you *could* make it work using these techniques.

That said, here a "pure" Html Agility Pack / XPATH implementation:

```
var pNodes = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//p[text()='=.+=']");
```

It uses a filter (between [ and ]) and the standard XPATH function text() which means "inner text".

Comment: Thank you Simon!  Google'ing around wasn't helping.

Answer (score 4):

Apparently HtmlAgilityPack doesn't handle namespaces (not that I had one).  So I've come up with this hack,

```
var pNodes = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//p")
    .Where(node => Regex.Match(node.InnerText, "^=.+=$").Success);
```

If there is an HtmlAgilityPack solution I'd love to hear it!

Answer (score 0):

To echo what Simon Mourier said, The re:test() function is not a core XPath function. It is available in Calibre's XPath function set (http://manual.calibre-ebook.com/xpath.html#term-re-test), but that is a non-standard extension. I am not aware of any other systems, besides Calibre, that may expose the re:test() function.

For a good summary of core XPath functions and XSLT extension functions, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions